# Another regex question

Tags: java, regex

If I have the text

```
<page a>The cat ran#$(*#(%)#over(*@#$the(*#%
```

and am using a scanner and the useDelimiter method, what regex would allow me to extract:

```
<page a>
The
cat
ran
over
the
```

So far I have tried:

```
s.useDelimiter("[^a-zA-Z]|^(<.*>$)");
```

but that does not leave angle brackets intact, it takes them out (obviously as it matches the a-zA-Z instead.

Comment: Also, you probably want `.*?` instead of `.*`, since `*` on its own is greedy (and would match <foo>bar<foo2> all in one go -- from the opening `<` to the last closing `>`)

Comment: could you do a better job summarizing your question in the title rather than "another regex question"? I think it makes the site more useful if the title summarizes the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not one of delimiters, so much as it is one of token recognition. Your tokens are:

- `<page a>`
- `The`
- `cat`
- `ran`
- `over`
- `the`

Encoding the "<" characters anywhere in the set of delimiters pretty much ensures that they *won't* be in the returned tokens. If you know that the `<page a>` occurs at the beginning of the string somewhere (and I realize that might be an invalid assumption), you can do something like this:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(...);
s.useDelimiter("[^\\w]");
// Find an angle bracket token, if one is next.
String token = s.findInLine("<[^.]*>");
if (token != null)
    // process angle bracket token
token = s.next(); // get next delimited token
...
```

Obviously, that's a quick hack (though I did test it). But you could easily extend it, I think.

Comment: +1 for nice answer. By the way, `findInLine` ignores delimiter (see javadoc), so you the `s.useDelimiter("..")` part is redundant.

Comment: Yes, I know. But the s.useDelimiter() part is necessary to set the delimiter to `not \w` (that is, any non-word character). Otherwise, the scanner won't skip the punctuation characters, because it defaults to using white space as the delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try switching both options?

```
s.useDelimiter("^(<.*>$)|[^a-zA-Z]");
```

Comment: yeah, doesn't change anything.

Comment: The `(<.*>$)` part isn't matching since there is no tag that spans an entire line in you input. Try removing the `$`.

Comment: It is now s.useDelimiter("^(<.*?>)|[^a-zA-Z]") but still isn't working because it will always just match the a-z class instead.